# Transitioning From A Large Image to a Smaller Image Using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, transition

i have a header that uses two images for a background, one appears when the webpage is scrolled at the very top and the other one is a smaller one that appears when the page is scrolled down. The demo is available here: `harrisonbh.com/dev/transitions`

I am wanting the transition between the two to be smooth, but I am not familiar whatsoever with JavaScript, so I am completely lost.

The code for the header div transition is:

```
$(function(){
    $('#header').data('size','big');
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(document).scrollTop() > 0)
    {
        if($('#header').data('size') == 'big')
        {
            $('#header').data('size','small');
            $('#header').stop().animate({
                height:'100px'
            },600);

            $('#logo').stop().animate({
                height: '100px'
            },600);

           document.getElementById("logo").style.backgroundImage="url('hub_test_files/arih_header_v2_small.png')";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if($('#header').data('size') == 'small')
        {
            $('#header').data('size','big');
            $('#header').stop().animate({
                height:'275px'
            },600);

            $('#logo').stop().animate({
                height: '272px'
            },600);

            document.getElementById("logo").style.backgroundImage="url('hub_test_files/arih_header_v2.png')";
        }  
    }
});
```

I did try to both CSS and JS transitions and they both did not seem to work, so for now and for future viewers of this question, is there any way to transition between a larger and a smaller image in JS? Thank you.

`Note: The website that I am using to change the header on is not mine, just me experimenting, but I intend to give the final code to the owner.`